# Twitter Bootstrap - dropdown with div content instead of a list

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

What's the recommended way to do this?

Here's an example of what I've done http://jsfiddle.net/T9QHw/56/
Normal dropdown on the left, and the div version on the right.

But the div acts a little funny. It closes itself if I click on it, and styles `a` tags as blocks.

Should I be doing this a different way?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Perhaps you want to be using the [Popover](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers) component instead of the Dropdown component?